# Why this code works in 2 Keys Keyboard question in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, iteration, dynamic-programming

I was solving this [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/2-keys-keyboard/) which is pretty interesting in leetcode and I found a solution for this.Though this iterative approach works,I want to know the logical thinking behind this solution.

Question:

There is only one character 'A' on the screen of a notepad. You can perform two operations on this notepad for each step:

- Copy All: You can copy all the characters present on the screen (a partial copy is not allowed).
- Paste: You can paste the characters which are copied last time.

Given an integer n, return the minimum number of operations to get the character 'A' exactly n times on the screen.

Example testcases:

Input: n = 3
Output: 3
Explanation: Intitally, we have one character 'A'.
In step 1, we use Copy All operation.
In step 2, we use Paste operation to get 'AA'.
In step 3, we use Paste operation to get 'AAA'.

My code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int minSteps(int n) {
        int res=0;
        for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
        {
            while(n%i==0)
            {
                res+=i;
                n=n/i;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

The code is pretty simple,Just need to understand the intuition behind it.

Thanks

Comment: check out this https://www.programmersought.com/article/17741862524/